# Why can I move an object with deleted move constructor and assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++17, move, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have the following definitions:

```
struct FileDescriptor {
    explicit FileDescriptor(int fd) : desc(fd), is_open(true) {}

    explicit operator int() { return desc; }

    FileDescriptor(const FileDescriptor &) = delete;

    FileDescriptor(FileDescriptor &&) = delete;

    FileDescriptor &operator=(const FileDescriptor &) = delete;

    FileDescriptor &operator=(FileDescriptor &&) = delete;

    ~FileDescriptor() {
        if (is_open) {
            close(desc);
        }
    }

    int desc;
    bool is_open;
};

std::string capture_out(FileDescriptor &&fd) {
    /* some code */
}
```

As you can see, the move constructor and assignment operator of the FileDescriptor structure are explicitly deleted. However, the following code compiles.

```
/* some code */
FileDescriptor fdhERR(6);

auto sERR = capture_out(std::move(fdhERR));
/* some code */
```

I am not very familiar with the intricacies of rvalue, but such behavior seems counterintuitive. Why does it happen?

Comment: `std::move` just casts things to R Values. A move only happens if your class allows it otherwise it just treats the argument as another rvalue. Use a debugger and follow the code and you will see what's happening. An R value is a value without an associated name. like `round(3.0)` the 3.0 is an R value. Probably a duplicate.

Comment: Also, it's `capture_out` that uses the R-value ness of the argument. Nothing to do with FileDescriptor

Comment: You should show what the code is in `capture_out`. Does it ever use the `FileDescriptor` parameter? Does it ever attempt to copy/move it?

Comment: There is nothing to construct. Your function gets its parameter by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`capture_out()` takes an rvalue reference as its parameter, but it is still just a reference nonetheless. `std::move()` is just a typecast to a reference, it doesn't actually move anything. Your example constructs only one `FileDescriptor` object and then passes it by reference to `capture_out()`, there is no second object being constructed or assigned to, so your deleted constructors and deleted operators are not called. Nothing is actually being copied or moved.